# How can I use tabhost + viewpager without call fragment twice?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabhost

MainActivity

```
 private void setupTabHost() {

    for(int i=0; i<tabs.length; i++) {
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(tabs[i].getLabel()).setIndicator(tabs[i].getLabel()), MyFragment.class, null);
    }
}
```

ViewPager

```
List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, MainActivity.TabData[] tabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.tabs = tabs;
    for(MainActivity.TabData tab : tabs){
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("URL", tab.getUrl());
        MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        fragmentList.add(fragment);
    }
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem (int i) {
    return fragmentList.get(i);
}
```

Can this `ViewPager` call the original fragment that was created by `tabhost`?
This code seems like, it will create a new `fragment` from `list<Fragment>`?

Comment: If you want to add tabs dynamically at run time (as per your webservice response) , then YES .this code will generate new instance of fragment every time.

Comment: Use `TabLayout` and viewPager.